# Failed to read the project file in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, github, rss-reader

Hi i have imported the android BBC_NEWS_READER application from [here](https://github.com/okey666/BBC-News-Reader)

Here i have added the library from [here](https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss)

But when I import the RSSFeed app I am getting following error.

The Error is :

```
Failed to read the project file in android eclipse (.project) for 'android-rss-master'.
The file has been changed on disk,and it contains invalid information.
The project will not function properly until the description file is restored to a valid state.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Download the Zip files.(BBC-News-Reader) and the Library(android-rss).
- Keep the application(BBC-News-Reader) and the library(android-rss) in a single folder, and select that folder for import.
- Right click on ReaderActivity(BBC-News-Reader)->properties->android
- add "android-rss-master" library. select some other target SDK if there exists target resolving issue.
- Note: You also need ActionBarSherlock and View Pager library to make it work.

Comment: i have added the all library files.but am getting following error on my console window:02-08 04:39:26.472: E/AndroidRuntime(308): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
02-08 04:39:26.472: E/AndroidRuntime(308): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mcsoxford.rss.RSSReader
02-08 04:39:26.472: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.RSSManager.run(RSSManager.java:63)
02-08 04:39:26.472: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
How can i resolve these error.

Comment: https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss Check out the read me section of it. Hope it helps